# Why isn't Heroku reading my Django urls.py?

Tags: django, heroku, django-urls

I successfully deploy using `git push heroku master`, but when I click "open app" inside heroku, I receive this message. I've looked at so many different threads and solutions I think I'm starting to make a mess of my settings file.

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'politicalexperimentpollapp.urls'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://politicalexperiment.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'politicalexperimentpollapp.urls'
Exception Location: <frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _find_and_load_unlocked, line 965
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python37.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

> My folder structure:

/Users/Jamie/politicalexperimentpoll/

- politicalexperimentpollproject (contains wsgi, urls.py, settings.py, etc.)
- politicalexperimentpollapp (contains urls.py)
- manage.py
- Procfile
- runtime.txt
- requirements.txt
- venv
- .vscode

> urls.py in project folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('politicalexperimentpollapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

> urls.py in app folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('tr', views.tr, name='tr'),
...
]
```

> settings.py

```
import django_heroku
import os

SECRET_KEY = x

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127...my ip', 'politicalexperiment.herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'politicalexperimentpollapp',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'politicalexperimentpollproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'politicalexperimentpollproject.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'NAME': 'politicalexperimentpoll',
'USER': 'postgres',
'PASSWORD': 'x',
'HOST': 'x',
'PORT': 'x',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

import dj_database_url 
prod_db  =  dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(prod_db)

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

> Here is more error language I get in the terminal:

```
(venv) Jamies-MacBook-Pro-2:politicalexperimentpoll Jamie$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ politicalexperiment... up, run.7006 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 65, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/politicalexperimentpollproject/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('', include('politicalexperimentpollapp.urls')),
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

Comment: have you tried with the project name like :

`path('', include('politicalexperimentpollproject.politicalexperimentpollapp.urls')),`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get the same kind of error: ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'politicalexperimentpollproject.politicalexperimentpollapp'

Comment: @Szakaria is it ok if i move all of the content from politicalexperimentpollapp.urls.py to the urls.py file in the project folder? I assume that wouldn't be readable that way?

Comment: yeas you can bbut it's not a good practice , try remove quotes from `'politicalexperimentpollapp.urls' = >path('', include(politicalexperimentpollapp.urls)),`